# Show that if  is an integer greater than 1 and , ,  ∈ ℤ then  ≡  mod  if and only if  ≡  mod (  gcd(,) ).

Tags: number-theory

I simplified it down to (a - b) * (gcd(,)) /  and ( - ) * c /  so I was thinking that I need to prove that c = (gcd(,)) but I was wondering how important the (a-b) is.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! This is false. Counter-example: $3\times 2\equiv 0\times 2\mod 6$, but $3\not\equiv 0\mod 12$.

Comment: I only see "if box and box are box then box equals box mod box".